# Change ID in last paragraph with preg_replace (PHP/Regex)

Tags: php, regex

The following script gives every paragraph a numerical ID, beginning with [p class="pfirst" id="1"] and [p id="2"], where $Article is an article stored in a database. (Only the first paragraph has a class.)

If there are ten articles in a paragraph, the last paragraph tag will be [p id="10"]. Can any regex wizards tell me how to modify it so that the last paragraph always displays as [p id="Last"] instead of a numerical ID?

```
$c = 1;
$r = preg_replace('/(<p( [^>]+)?>)/ie', '"<p\2 id=\"" . $c++ . "\">"', $Article);
$Article = $r;
```

---

Here's the entire script...

```
$SeaURL = str_replace('Washington/', '', $MyURL);

$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT P.URL, P.Site, ART.Article
 FROM people P
 LEFT JOIN people_articles ART ON ART.URL = P.URL
 WHERE P.URL LIKE :MyURL AND P.Site = :MySiteID
 GROUP BY Class");
$stm->execute(array(
 'MySiteID'=>$MySiteID, 
 'MyURL'=>'%'.$MyURL.'%'
));

while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $Article = $row['Article'];
}

$c = 1;
$r = preg_replace('/(<p( [^>]+)?>)/ie', '"<p\2 id=\"" . $c++ . "\">"', $Article);
$Article = $r;

 $Content = str_replace('$Name_Common', '<span style="color: #900"><strong>'.$Common.'</strong></span>', $Article);

echo $Content;
```

Comment: Please give more code, an example string and what you want to obtain with this example string because it is ununderstandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it:

```
//$Article ="<p class=\"pfirst\">paragraph 1</p><p>paragraph 2</p><p>paragraph 3</p>";
$c = 1;
$r = preg_replace('/(<p( [^>]+)?>)/ie', '"<p\2 id=\"" . $c++ . "\">"', $Article);
$r = preg_replace('/(<p.*?)id="'.($c-1).'"(>)/i', '\1id="Last"\2', $r);
$Article = $r;
```

Note: it is a dangerous way of playing with `e` modifier, though, cause some of the code in your `p` tags becomes php executable.

**EDIT:** Also the `e` modifier is being depricated, so below is a better and safer alternative:

```
$c = 1;
$r = preg_replace_callback('/(<p( [^>]+)?>)/i', function ($res) {
   global $c;
   return '<p'.$res[2].' id="'.intval($c++).'">';
}, $Article);
$r = preg_replace('/(<p.*?)id="'.($c-1).'"(>)/i', '\1id="Last"\2', $r);
$Article = $r;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "php executable." Are you saying using this script will enable people to hack my web pages?

Comment: Theoretically, yes - it makes it more volnurable. If some of the p tags in your articals will have <p ... php code here ... > it will execute it. It is kind of OK (too long to explain in comments), as long as you yourself put the content in your db, but it would still be safer to use preg_replace_callback or something of that sort instead.

Comment: The use of `e` modifier is now deprecated. Use `preg_replace_callback()` instead.

Comment: OK, I replaced preg_replace with preg_replace_callback, but I get a couple error messages - Warning: preg_replace_callback() [function.preg-replace-callback]: Requires argument 2, '"<p\2 id=\"" . $c++ . "\">"', to be a valid callback in (PATH) on line 227

Warning: preg_replace_callback() [function.preg-replace-callback]: Requires argument 2, '\1id="Last"\2', to be a valid callback

They aren't fatal errors, but the script doen't work; it doesn't insert ID's in paragraph tags now.